# Biblatex custom cite command

Tags: biblatex, citing

I recently started using `biblatex` and I'm looking for some custom cite commands. The `\footfullcite` takes up too much space so I wanted to create some `\footcite` command myself that would only produce lets say the `title`, `url`, and `urldate`.

The *readme* tells me where to look for the definitions of the commands so I can change them.

Looking up the `\footfullcite` macro I get this:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

There are not too many lines of code but I don't see how I could change it so it only shows the  `title`, `url` and `urldate`. Could anyone give me a small example of how to make/change such a cite command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I started with the `\citetitle` command and added the functionality of the `url+urldate` bibmacro (plus punctuation and spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcitetitleurl}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}
   \setunit{\adddot\space}
   \usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2011-02-12}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.\footcitetitleurl{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx, with this example i can edit the others myself.