# Using Biblatex with Multind to make an automated author index

Tags: biblatex, indexing

I am starting a book which I want to have separate author and subject indices. While I've made indices by hand in the past, I am considering shifting to  biblatex in part because it says it automates putting citations and bibliographic entries into "the index".  I can't find any indication whether this supports multiple indices.  (The publisher wants me to use the package multind for the multiple indices).  I only want to put authors names in the author index automagically.

I can't even find the name of the .idx file that biblatex tells me I have to run makeindex on.  Any guidance, especially sample code, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. *the .idx file that biblatex tells me I have to run makeindex on* Where did you get a name and what is the name of the `idx` file?

Comment: `biblatex` does not produce an index for you. You still need an index package and all its index setup and printing commands. `biblatex` only issues `\index`. It would be possibly to direct `biblatex` to use multiple indices, but how that would work depends on what exactly you have in mind. Can you share your index setup so far and what exactly you have in mind in an example document, please?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68016/35864 has examples with `biblatex` and `multind`

Comment: An exsample file `…/doc/latex/biblatex/examples/22-indexing-subentry.tex`  using `imakeidx` is part of the `biblatex` docu. You can search for it with the file search feature of your OS. Using `imakeidx` is, i.e, for beginners often easier than using `multind`, because it does all the `makeindex` runs on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to look at the sample files that come with biblatex.  With that and a LOT of experimenting, I solved my problems.

Second, this is NOT compatible with the multindex package that my publisher wants me to use but does work with the index package.  If any reader has question, contact me at bsimon@caltech.edu.  

Thanks for your help.

First, the index that biblatex puts the index items in is just <name>.ind if the source is <name>.tex.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post a short answer in the answer section so that others can benefit from it.