# How to customize bibliography style in beamer while using biblatex?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, biber

I want to customize the appearance of `\footfullcite` in my beamer presentation. I would like it to look something like this,
M. A. Zeb et. el., Phys. Rev. Lett., 108, 2012. I don't want to have the title and the page number etc. And in text reference to appear inline instead of a superscript enclosed in square brackets.
I have tried [these guidelines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/33567) but it doesn't seem to work.

I have saved the following

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\clearfield{title}%
\clearfield{pagetotal}%
}
```

in `biblatex.cfg` and saved it in     `/Users/ruawan/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex`.

Here is the input

```
\documentclass[13pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newtheorem{theor}{Theorem}
\usetheme{umbc2} 
\usecolortheme[named=RawSienna]{structure} 
\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\rmfamily,shape=\itshape} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center] 
\addbibresource{HinGe.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Previous Work}
\framesubtitle{Simple metals and beyond}
Simple metals have been reasonably well understood \footfullcite{maz01}.
\begin{itemize}
\item Linear response treatment by Lindhard.
\item The full non-linear treatment by Echenique, Ritchie, and Nieminen.
\item For simple metals the electronic stopping power is proportional to the projectile velocity in low-speed regime\footfullcite{maz02}.
\item Insulators, semiconductors, and noble metals are relatively poorly understood.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

Can you please point out the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to adjust the citation that appears with `\fullfootcite`, which is a citation, not a bibliography item.  So the appropriate way to clear the fields as you desire is to include

```
\AtEveryCitekey{%
\clearfield{title}%
\clearfield{pagetotal}%
}
```

in the preamble of the document.  You should also be able to include it in `biblatex.cfg` for a more universal application, but note that this will then affect any of your documents, and might be harder to find it once you've forgotten about this change. ;-)

#### Edit

The extra functionality you are asking about can be done with this code in the preamble.

```
% Make bracketized
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{[\arabic{footnote}]}
\makeatletter
% Remove superscript for footnotemark
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
% Allow space to precede the footnote
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\blx@mkbibfootnote}{\unspace}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks. It removes the titles but page number entry is there yet.

Comment: Sometimes, when you remove one field, another will take its place.  A record with both `title` and `subtitle` may have the subtitle still appear, or perhaps the `shorttitle` will take its place.  In this case `pages` probably also needs to be cleared.  It is dependent on your bib-file.

Comment: Got it. It works.

Comment: Apologies for bothering once more. I would like the in text reference in line instead of a superscript and enclosed in square brackets. Can you please help with it as well? [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10932/33567) a similar question has been asked and answered but I couldn't tweak for my purpose.

Comment: @R.U. : If my answer was useful for you, please upvote it (this has to be done separately from accepting it).

Comment: Many many thanks. I have edited my question accordingly. Yes your answer was very useful but I can't up vote as I don't have the minimum reputation (15) to up vote an answer.